# What is the difference between Registry and Repository from SOA point of view?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, soa

- What is difference between Registry
  and Repositry from SOA point of view
  ?
- Which one should be used ? What are pros and cons of one over other and vice-versa ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/woolf/Registry+vs.+Repository

*"A registry is a list of items with pointers for where to find the items, like the index on a database table or the card catalog for a library. A repository stores the actual items, like a database table itself or a library's shelves of books. If you lose a registry, the items still exist; you just may need to reindex them. If you lose a repository, the items are gone."*